# ASP.Net repeator, click and go to respective record on next page.How?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, repeater

i worked in PHP before and used to use window.location function with javascript function, please let me know how to tackle the functionality in repeator,
record 1
 record 2
 record 3

I want if some one clicks on a label, it should go to other page, page.aspx?id=1  or id=7 respectively

I dont want to use javascript window.location, is there any built in asp.net option in repeater to do so, i have passed postback url to page.aspx.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Drop a [DataPager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx) in your page and set it's [PagedControlID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.pagedcontrolid.aspx) attribute to your repeater's ID

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" PagedControlID="Repeater1" PageSize="5" runat="server">
</asp:DataPager>
```

**Update:**

Apparently DataPager doesn't like Repeater, so I suggest using [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) instead. In the end ListView is very much like Repeater but more flexible.

Comment: Error occured:  Control 'Repeater1' does not implement IPageableItemContainer.

Comment: Is there a chance you could change to ListView? Which in the end is just the more flexible version of Repeater as it allows you to template it, and many more good additions. I'm sure it works with ListView as I have used it many times. I will update my answer.